# How do you get rid of right indents in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm having an issue pop up in Excel 2010 where certain cells appear to have what can only be described as a right or left indent: depending on the justification, there will be a sliver of unused space on the left or right side of a cell populated with text. The problem persists even though indents are set to 0. In addition, the unused space does not appear to be connected with wrap text and the size of the next word.

The problem only occurs in this document in unmerged cells. But if you merge two cells with the problem the issue persists. So I don't think it's connected to whether or not the cells are merged. The unused space also increases and decreases in size as column width increases or decreases.

The only other thing i can think of is that it might have something to do with the fact that all of the text in my document has been pasted in from a Word document. but I would imagine there is a way to fix it.

So, has anyone experienced this problem and, if so, can you offer suggestions for fixing it? Let me know if clarification is needed.

See the below picture for an example of what I mean. In this instance F1 is what I consider normal for this document. I want to be rid of the unused space on the right of cells F2 through F8. This problem also occurs in columns G-J.

["Indent" Error Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjA4v.png)

Here is the [example document](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bvzrw3it9leoclf/IndentErrorExample.xlsx?dl=0) if anybody has time to poke around.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you're pasting from an ordered list. After pasting, does the problem resolve after pressing `Ctrl` and then pressing `M` (Paste values only)? It looks like that extra space is protecting the kerning which will be resolved if you are not preserving the bullets.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Is there a simple way to remove the space or is it a matter of deleting the rows and copy pasting unbulleted text?

Comment: I'm suggesting you paste the text without the bullets.